# Preparing for a feature request for more flexibility and control over moving comments to chat rooms

Tags: discussion, chat, comments

"Comments are not for extended discussion", the Stack Exchange system always tells us if it detects two people getting into a 2-way discussion in the comments of a question or answer.

However when inviting a user to a chat room as below:

[image]

there is currently no feature available to transfer (or at least copy) the comments in the *existing* discussion into the new chat room, ***unless creating a brand new chat room,*** [which I think is extremely inelegant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353643/391772).

My first [feature-request](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), which you can see in the above link, was unsuccessful (in my opinion due to just one user who unfairly attacked the idea). However, I think the above screenshot is a perfect example of why the entire SE company (not just me!) would actually like for there to be such a feature. Therefore I propose that we keep in this Meta discussion, a record of such examples as this one, in the spirit of accumulating enough data to make the [feature-request](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) successful.

Comment: Another good example: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3968/5

Comment: Another good example: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2015/5 (see comments on the answer that turned into the PHONOPY room).

Comment: A great example: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4100/5